# GET request does not have latest entry inside

Tags: reactjs

I made an Event Feed in React. Here is the structure (I've removed unrelated components:

```
App.js
|_EventFeed.js
|_EventCreate.js
```

My problem is this:
When I create an event in EventCreate, I hope for the EventFeed to update with the latest entry but it does not happen. It does update eventually after a few seconds or refreshes - and I think this delay is because I'm using free Heroku dynos on the back-end.

How can I make it update automatically?

Code here:

EventFeed.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Row,
  Col,
  CardBody,
  CardSubtitle,
  Container,
  CardText,
  CardTitle,
  Progress,
} from 'reactstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import Loader from '../images/loader.gif';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import nightWorkout from "../images/nightWorkout.jpg";

class EventFeed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: true,
      eventsList: [],
      isLoading: true,
      eventsJoined:0
    }
  }

  //retrieve all events via axios
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://final-project-healthy.herokuapp.com/api/v1/events/')
      .then(response => {
        let tempEventList = response.data;
        this.setState({ eventsList: tempEventList, isLoading: false })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR: ', error);
      })
  }

  refreshFeed = () =>{
    axios.get('https://final-project-healthy.herokuapp.com/api/v1/events/')
      .then(response => {
        let tempEventList = response.data;
        this.setState({ eventsList: tempEventList, isLoading: false })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR: ', error);
      })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.refreshFeed();
  }

  handleSubmit = e =>{
    //make an api call to guestlist and add or delete current user to guest list
    let event_id = e.target.id
    let JWT = localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    axios.post('https://final-project-healthy.herokuapp.com/api/v1/guestlists/',
    {event_id:event_id},
      {
        headers:{
            Authorization: `Bearer ${JWT}`
            }
      }
    ).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.refreshFeed();
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log("ERROR in request: ", error)
  })
}

  render() {
    const { eventsList, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${nightWorkout})`, backgroundSize:'cover', backgroundAttachment:'fixed', height:'100wh'}}>
        <div>
          <h1 className="text-center text-light shadow">Events Near You</h1>
          <h4 className="text-center text-light shadow">Don't see a fitness meet you like? How about <Link to={'/events/create'}>creating your own</Link>?</h4>
          {isLoading ?
            <Container>
              <Row className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <img src={Loader} alt="Loading event feed" />
              </Row>
            </Container>
            :
            eventsList.map((eventInList) => {
              let guestlist=[]
              if (eventInList.guests.includes(this.props.current_user.id)){
                console.log('The user is here!')
              }
              return (
                <Container key={eventInList.id} className="my-2 bg-none">
                    <Row md="10" className="d-flex align-items-center rounded bg-info" style={{opacity:'0.9'}}>
                      <Col md="4" className=" d-flex justify-content-center align-item-center rounded">
                        <img width="200px" height="200px" className="border border-white m-3 rounded justify-content-center" src={eventInList.image} alt="event image" />
                      </Col>
                       <Col md="8" className="rounded">
                        <CardBody className="p-1 text-left">
                          <CardTitle><h3 className='text-light'>{eventInList.name}</h3></CardTitle>
                          <CardSubtitle className='text-light'>{eventInList.time}</CardSubtitle>
                          <CardText className='text-light'>Host : {eventInList.host.username}</CardText>
                          <CardText className='text-light'>Location:{eventInList.location}<br/>What to expect:{eventInList.description}</CardText>
                          <CardText className="text-light">Capacity: {eventInList.guests.length}/{eventInList.max_number}</CardText>
                          <Row className="align-items-center">
                            <Col md="8">
                              <Progress color="success" value={Math.floor(eventInList.guests.length/eventInList.max_number*100)} />
                            </Col>
                            <Col md="4">
                            {eventInList.guests.includes(this.props.current_user.id)
                               ?
                                <Button id={eventInList.id} color="danger" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Leave</Button>
                              :
                                <Button id={eventInList.id} color="success" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Join</Button>
                            }
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                        </CardBody>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>)
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default EventFeed;
```

EventCreate.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Card,
    CardImg,
    CardText,
    Button,
    Col,
    Form,
    FormText,
    FormGroup,
    Input,
    Label,
    Row,
} from "reactstrap"
import axios from 'axios';
import PlacesWithStandaloneSearchBox from "../components/PlacesWithStandaloneSearchBox";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Loader from "../images/loader.gif";
import morningRun from "../images/morning_run.jpg"

class EventCreate extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.imageUpload=React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            eventName: '',
            description: '',
            location: '',
            time: '',
            maxNumber: '',
            isLoading:false,
            previewImage:null,
            imageFile:null,
            message:''
        }
    }

handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value }, () => {
        //for debugging purposes, this ensures that the state is updated with the field values
        for (const key in this.state) {
            if (this.state.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(key + " -> " + this.state[key] + ` of data type ${typeof (this.state[key])}`);
            }
        }
    })
    console.clear()
}

liftMyLocationUp = locationFromGoogle => {
    this.setState({ location: locationFromGoogle })
}

//handleSubmit lifts up field values 
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("image_file", this.state.imageFile, this.state.imageFile.name);
    formData.append("name", this.state.eventName);
    formData.append("description", this.state.description);
    formData.append("max_number", this.state.maxNumber);
    formData.append("time", this.state.time);
    formData.append("location", this.state.location);

    console.log('handleSubmit called')
    this.registerEvent(formData);
    setTimeout(() => this.props.history.push('/events'), 2000);
}

handleFile = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.files[0])
    this.setState({
        imageFile:e.target.files[0],
        previewImage:URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
    })
}

//necessary to setState? why not just keep it as props or make ?
registerEvent = (formData) => {
    let JWT = localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    axios.post('https://final-project-healthy.herokuapp.com/api/v1/events/',
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${JWT}`
            }
        }
    ).then(response => {
        if (response.data.success){
            console.log(response.data.success)
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("ERROR in request: ", error);
    })
}

handleClick = () =>{
    this.imageUpload.current.click();
}

render() {
    const { event_name, description, location, max_number, time, isLoading, previewImage, imageFile, message } = this.state
    return (
        <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${morningRun})`, backgroundSize:'cover', height:'100vh'}}>
            <h3 className="text-center text-light">Create Your Event Here:</h3>
            <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <Col lg="4" md="5" sm="12" className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <Form className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <FormGroup >
                            <Label for="eventName" className="text-light">Event Name:</Label>
                            <Input id="eventName" type="text" value={event_name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Give me a name"></Input>
                            <Label for="description" className="text-light">Description:</Label>
                            <Input id="description" type="text" value={description} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Share what I'm about"></Input>
                            <Label for="location" className="text-light">Location:</Label>
                            <PlacesWithStandaloneSearchBox liftMyLocationUp={this.liftMyLocationUp} />
                            {/* <Input id="location" type="text" value={location} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Tell folks where to find me"></Input> */}
                            <Label for="time" className="text-light">Time:</Label>
                            <Input id="time" type="datetime-local" value={time} onChange={this.handleChange}></Input>
                            <Label for="maxNumber" className="text-light">Max Number:</Label>
                            <Input id="maxNumber" type="number" min="0" value={max_number} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="It's always better with company"></Input>
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                </Col>


                <Col lg="4" md="5" sm="12" className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <Row>
                    <Form>
                    <FormGroup>
                    <Label className="d-block text-light">Upload your event image here:</Label>
                        <div id="image-preview" onClick={this.handleClick}>

                            <Card style={{width:"300px", height:"300px"}} className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                {/* Set loading icon when uploading picture. nested ternary operator. */}
                                {!isLoading?(!imageFile?(<h4 className="text-center">{message ? message : "Click to upload"}</h4>):(<CardImg src={previewImage} height="300px" width="300px"/>)):<Loader/>}
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                        <input id="upload" style={{display:"none"}} type="file" accept="image/*" multiple={false} name="image-file" ref={this.imageUpload} id="imageFile" onChange={this.handleFile}></input>
                    </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup>
                        <div id="image-submit-form">
                                <Row >
                                    <Col md={12} sm={12}>


                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                        </div>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <Button color="primary" className="text-light" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Create Event</Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default EventCreate;
```

Comment: Either you:
1. Check every set amount time for updates. 
2. Use Firebase or socket.io (FeathersJS can simplify that) to listen for changes 
3. If both are in the same codebase, register `EventFeed` to listen for the `registerEvent` event

Comment: @C493d,  could you explain about option 1 & 3?

Comment: 1. Set a looping timeout and fetch changes each time the timeout finishes in the `EventFeed`
3. Something like this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events - only that it will react to local changes (when you submit) and not to db/remote changes